# JQuery Character encoding problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, encode, url-encoding

My jquery code is sending the encoded characters via AJAX which are giving error on my server end, as they are not supported in the CMS which I am using. Is there a way I can send the exact characters rather than the ASCII values. Do I need the character set?

Below is what is getting passed in the query

```
?search_query=new%2Bcommunity%26fq%3Dtype%3Aboard
```

**expected**

```
?search_query=new+community&fq=type:board
```

**Ajax Code**

where kb_endpoint_url is the api which I am hitting, with queryValue as the **q=**, which is new community and parameters as the string of the parameters, which is **&fq=type:board**

```
$.getJSON( "${kb_endpoint_url}", { search_query : queryValue+parameters } )
    .done(function( data, xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(data);
        //code here
    })              
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(status); 
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("finished");
    });
```

Comment: Show your ajax code...

Comment: updated the original question

Comment: console.log(${kb_endpoint_url}); and post the result please